# Jquery draggable sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I ve a container

```
<div id="contenitore" class="connectedSortable"></div>
```

whit this Jq code

```
$( "#contenitore" ).sortable({
update: function(event, ui){
ElementAppend();},
connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

and an other div like

```
<div class="element-container"></div>
```

whit this Jq code for handle some dragging event

```
$("div.element-container").draggable({ 
  cursor: "move", cursorAt: { top: 20, left: 20 },
  drag: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).addClass("handled");
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
       $(this).removeClass("handled");
    },
  }).disableSelection();
```

so all sims work fine,but if i add

```
connectToSortable: ".connectedSortable"
```

to draggable i get this strange error

TypeError: e(...).data(...) is undefined

and the code dosent work

---

i ve try to find a solution, if can help who will answer.

thhe code before is in a wpress teme.
So i ve tryed all in a simply HTML JS page and the error now is

> TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined
>
> var o = $(this).data("ui-draggable").options;
>
> in this code of jQuery UI - v1.10.3 - 2013-08-05

so i vtryed add a class ui-draggable to div but still dont work

Answer (score 2):

Put the `connectToSortable` in your `draggable` function.

jQuery Part:

```
  $("#container").sortable({  
     receive: function(event,ui){  
        ui.item.remove();
     }
   });

  $("#element-container").draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#container",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
  });
```

HTML Part:

```
  //First
  <div id="container"></div>
  //Second
  <div id="element-container"></div>
```

Comment: the question is if i add connectToSortable: ".connectedSortable" n  draggable function still dont work

Comment: @IlProfetaProfeta sorry for very late reply. If you have solved this, hope it help others. The **connectToSortable: ".connectedSortable"** should be put in your 2nd jQuery code, the **$('#element-container').draggable({...})**.

Hope this will help.